# A better word for transforming a software project from start to finish

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I `___` a (software) project from concept to implementation.

"___" here refers to being solely responsible for all phases of the [SDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) process for this project.

Comment: Could you tell us why words such as "led" and "managed" don't work for this?

Comment: Because I did not "Lead" any team in this project. It was done fully solo.

Comment: If you didn't lead then maybe you should [edit] your question so that it doesn't ask about leading.

Comment: Resumes usually say *designed and executed* the project. Mentioning the one-person aspect says it was a small project.

Comment: Similar to the comment that asks why *led* and *managed* are not acceptable, why is *I **was solely responsible for** a (software) project*, which is already used in the question itself, not acceptable? I can't imagine any single word being more idiomatic or comprehensive than that phrase.

Comment: I wonder if this question would be more appropriate for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think so, as its not technical enough, not addressing a coding/scripting issue.

Comment: I overhauled a software project, I re-organized a software project. Spearhead as a verb requires more than one person. If you redid it on your own, you didn't spearhead anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **spearheaded**? From M-W:

> **[spearhead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spearhead)**: to serve as leader or leading element of

Your example:

> I **spearheaded** a (software) project from concept to implementation.

**Spearhead** is commonly used in management circles, as is **champion**, although I can't find a definition of the latter consistent with my experience.

Comment: Thank you. I think this portrays what I want to convey clearly.

Comment: *Spearhead* implies the presence of spear, which is why the definition you've quoted is about being a leader, so I don't think it's the right word to describe a case where an entire project was completed by a single person.

Answer (score 0):

How about **self-executed** or **self-managed**? Alternatively, **individually executed** or **individually managed**.

You might also consider throwing in the word "solo", as in

> I self-executed a solo (software) project from concept to implementation.

or

> I self-managed a solo (software) project from concept to implementation.

or

> I individually executed a solo (software) project from concept to implementation.

or

> I individually managed a solo (software) project from concept to implementation.

Answer (score 0):

How about oversaw or oversee? This would describe your role in either a solo or group project.

I was tasked to oversee (software) project from concept to implementation.

I oversaw (software) project from concept to implementation.

Comment: To me, "oversee" heavily implies the management role as opposed to the individual contributor role.

Answer (score 0):

I piloted a (software) project from concept to implementation.

Comment: I think it's a good suggestion, but consistent with the expectations for answers on this site, could you provide a definition from a dictionary and a couple of examples of sentences where the verb _pilot_ is used in this way? You may want to visit the site's Help Center to read about good ELU answers.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging my suggestion. An example sentence from a dictionary would be: “the lead rider piloted the rest of the team“  from here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/piloted

Answer (score 0):

The word for transforming a software project is “refactoring”, except that makes little sense with your examples. Maybe you want to change the title of the question.